# Reading csv lines in python open() not working when looking for empty first empty line

Tags: python, pandas, csv, readline

When reading line by line, at the first “empty” line, there is all commas. When I expect `\n`.

open

```
file = 'file.csv'
f = open(file)
```

and

```
f.readline()
```

gives me this

`‘,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n’`

Ironic but causing my code to read forever and never “finish”.

I want this to work:

```
f = open(file)

while f.readline() != '\n':
    pass

df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)

f.close()
```

The commas get in the way here. Essentially breaking the code. What am I missing? Why is one CSV file suddenly reading in lines like this? The other files I have are not showing commas when reading line by line.

The other files just show this

`‘\n’`

Comment: Can't you just read the file directly with pandas? `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)`

Comment: Your expectation of CSV format is incorrect. An "empty" row isn't an empty line, it's a line of empty values delimited by commas.

Comment: Hi @RJAdriaansen! -- I am using this ```while``` to skip an unpredictable amount of rows in CSV files. I know that what you are suggesting is possible. I am just not sure it is possible to skip an unpredictable amount of rows with it.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thank you for the response! Could you explain why in one instance there appears to be an empty line? And the code works?

Comment: @kb9alpp But you can simply skip the blank lines in read_csv: `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, skip_blank_lines=True)`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Ok, understood. To be perfectly honest I've tried that. My issues are from needing to "skip an unpredictable amount of rows" that have text. And, actually, once I find the first blank row, load the df.